# icinga2 - where to change client monitoring commands?

Tags: icinga, icinga2

system ubuntu 16.04

On master node where icinga2 is installed

```
#ls /etc/icinga2/repository.d/hosts/WIN-U52321E0BAK/
disk C%3A.conf  disk.conf  icinga.conf  load.conf  ping4.conf  

ping6.conf  procs.conf  swap.conf  users.conf

All conf files have save "dummy" check_command on them for example
#cat load.conf
object Service "load" {
import "satellite-service"
check_command = "dummy"
host_name = "WIN-U52321E0BAK"
zone = "WIN-U52321E0BAK"
}
```

I cant understand from where dummy command is called and how to customize the checks for warning and critical threshold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dummy command is defined in `/usr/share/icinga2/include/command-plugins.conf`, like so:

```
144 object CheckCommand "dummy" {
145     import "plugin-check-command"
146
147     command = [ 
148         PluginDir + "/check_dummy",
149         "$dummy_state$",
150         "$dummy_text$"
151     ]
152
153     vars.dummy_state = 0
154     vars.dummy_text = "Check was successful."
155 }
```

In order to modify the warn and crit levels, you set the custom variable at the host or service level. Using the example of ping, we see the default configuration in that same file:

```
36 template CheckCommand "ping-common" {
37     import "plugin-check-command"
38
39     command = [ PluginDir + "/check_ping" ]
40
41     arguments = {
42         "-H" = "$ping_address$"
43         "-w" = "$ping_wrta$,$ping_wpl$%"
44         "-c" = "$ping_crta$,$ping_cpl$%"
45         "-p" = "$ping_packets$"
46         "-t" = "$ping_timeout$"
47     }
48
49     vars.ping_wrta = 100
50     vars.ping_wpl = 5
51     vars.ping_crta = 200
52     vars.ping_cpl = 15
53 }
```

Here's the important bit:

```
49     vars.ping_wrta = 100
50     vars.ping_wpl = 5
51     vars.ping_crta = 200
52     vars.ping_cpl = 15
```

**So**: we go to our host or service definition, thusly (using `/etc/icinga2/conf.d/host.conf` and the `NodeName`/localhost definition which everybody has; comments removed):

```
18 object Host NodeName {
20   import "generic-host"
21
23   address = "127.0.0.1"
24   address6 = "::1"
25
27   vars.os = "Linux"
30   vars.http_vhosts["http"] = {
31     http_uri = "/"
32   }
37
39   vars.disks["disk"] = {
41   }
42   vars.disks["disk /"] = {
43     disk_partitions = "/"
44   }
45 }
```

And we insert before line 45 above to produce:

```
18 object Host NodeName {
20   import "generic-host"
21
23   address = "127.0.0.1"
24   address6 = "::1"
25
27   vars.os = "Linux"
30   vars.http_vhosts["http"] = {
31     http_uri = "/"
32   }
37
39   vars.disks["disk"] = {
41   }
42   vars.disks["disk /"] = {
43     disk_partitions = "/"
44   }
45   vars.ping_wrta = 50
46   vars.ping_wpl = 3
47   vars.ping_crta = 10
48   vars.ping_cpl = 2
49 }
```

...and you have successfully customized the check threshold. You can add those variables to a template or even a hostgroup (I think; better test that, I may be wrong).

Comment: Are there some option to change this setting from Icinga director?